# BBCode Regex is too greedy when trying to match pattern with a carriage return

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using **preg_replace** to match a BBCode pattern in a string and replace it with my own HTML.

My base pattern is as follows `\[col=([^"]+?)\]((.|\n)+)\[\/col\]\`

Now the string I am trying to run it on is:

```
[col=Test]

Test

[/col]



[col=Test2]
asd
[/col]
```

(Yes with those carriage returns like that :)

Now if I only have one [col] tag, it works A-ok, but with two col tags like that it matches only the outer tages and places everything inside one big match instead of two separate matches.  I think my ((.|\n+) regex is simply too aggressive, but I can't figure out how to scale it back.  If I do a simple (.*?) then it will not match the first case with the carriage returns in it.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work for you http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php ? And I think there are many BBCode parser out there, why are you parsing it yourself?

Comment: "here is my regex" "it doesn't work in this situation". What does it mean for it to "work"? What pattern are you trying to match exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOTALL modifier `(?s)` to make dot to match also the line breaks.

```
(?s)\[col=([^"]+?)\](.+?)\[\/col\]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hK1uH1/7)

Comment: Tip of the hat sir.  This did it!  Will accept in 5 mins when allowed